# deleting the row from a variable in php after mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi Friends ,
             I need a small help to figure out how to delete the rows from 
table "Item" if "Item code" is there in  table  "Order_summery" for a particular subscriber.

table ## ITEM :

```
Item code   name    waight  cost    colour
8956        aaa      10     100     red 
2514        cccc     20     110     red 
7945        dddd     30     140     white
3156        eeee     40     90      black
```

table ### Order_summery:

```
oder    customer_iD     Item code   Bonus   cost
11265        45           7945       10     126
```

Code:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM ITEM";
$resultser=mysql_query($sql) or mysql_error(); 

$sql2= "SELECT * FROM Order_summery where customer_iD = 45 ";
$result=mysql_query($sql2) or mysql_error();
```

now how to delete the row number 4 of variable $sql as the same Item code is there in table "Order_summery"

Comment: See the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete records from table `item`  and keep records in `order_summary` table , then try this

```
 DELETE FROM item WHERE item_code IN (SELECT item_code FROM Order_Summary);
```

Comment: sorry dear ,  found a small mistake in the question . actually while querying the table iTEM i don't wanna have rows containing "item code" which is  present in the table Order_summery